# How to store and reuse a group of related constant values in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, enums, constants

So lets say I have a class Dog, and it has a lot of attributes like Hair Color, Weight, Length, Width

I then have an Enum of Dog breeds, so like `DogType.MASTIFF`

So if I'm instancing  a dog I can have `Dog dog = new Dog(DogType.POODLE)`

I'm doing this so I don't have to have a separate class for every single type of dog when the methods are the same, just the attributes change

So in the dog constructor you would have

```
switch(DogType){
    case MASTIFF:
      this.weight = 5
      this.height = 10
}
...
```

However, this would lead to a really large and unwieldy constructor for the Dog class.

What I'm asking is there a way where I can define a lot of constant values for each Enum? So instead of that switch statement it would be something like in the constructor given a DogType you can set the attributes with
`DogType.WEIGHT`

or for a specific type somewhere else in the code `DogType.MASTIFF.WEIGHT`

I feel like I'm missing something. In other languages I would have just made a sort of constant dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you want to have one class for each dog and inherit from a superclass (Dog)?

Comment: I don't think hard-coding weight and height via `switch` or attributes of an `enum` can be considered a good (and flexible) solution for this, but I don't know your exact requirements...

Comment: @bbrinck because data aren't meant to be inherited. Use composition instead.

Comment: @bbrinck in this case the data isn't meant to be inherited. Even if it was, I might want also want a constant source of truth for what all the attributes of a certain dog type are meant to be for use elsewhere in the program

Comment: @user3124306 Ok, in that case if would use Enums with constructors as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Enums with constructors: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html
In your case:

```
public enum DogType {
POODLE(2, 20), MASTIFF(40, 45);

private int weight;
private int height;

DogType(int weight, int height) {
    this.weight = weight;
    this.height = height;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
}
```

And then pass proper enum to your method and call getters.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're looking for is an Abstract Builder pattern. Very good explanation of the pattern is given here: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder/java/2

So, for your case, provided that you have an enum of dog types:

```
public enum DogType {
  MASTIFF,
  SOMEOTHERTYPE;
}
```

you can create your class this way:

```java
abstract class DogBuilder {
    public abstract Dog get();

    public DogBuilder getDogBuilder(DogType type) {
       switch(DogType){
          case MASTIFF:
             return new MastifDogBuilder();
          case SOMEOTHERTYPE:
             return new SomeOtherDogBuilder();
        }
    }
}

/* "ConcreteBuilder" */
class MastifDogBuilder extends DogBuilder {

    public Dog get() {
        dog = new Dog();
        dog.setHeight(10);
        dog.setWeight(5);
        return dog;
    }

}

/* "ConcreteBuilder" */
class SomeOtherDogBuilder extends PizzaBuilder {
    public Dog get() {
        dog = new Dog();
        dog.setHeight(20);
        dog.setWeight(5);
        return dog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, TIL  that I'm using this design pattern, however I think having the properties stored in an Enum is more concise still, like in the other answer - so I would be using both answers